# SwitchUserFilter with password-encoder not working

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I have a `<password-encoder>` and CustomDetailService refered in AuthenticationManager. I added the following bean in spring-security after all the other security filters (concurrency, customLogoutFilter, etc.,) and `<http auto-config="false" ..>`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
      /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Disable annotation-based method security -->
<global-method-security secured-annotations="disabled" />

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<!-- Service that provides user credentials for use by the authentication provider -->
<beans:bean id="customDetailService" class="xxx.security.CustomDetailService" />

<!-- Assign the user details service to the default authentication provider -->
<beans:bean class="xxx.security.XyzPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />

<!-- Get an alias to the default authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customDetailService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Register an exception filter that takes an entry point -->
<beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    <beans:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/public/auth/login.htmlx" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <beans:property name="errorPage" value="/error/access-denied.jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Register a custom authentication filter and register success/failure 
    handlers -->
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
        ref="concurrentSessionControlStrategy" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        ref="loginSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
        ref="loginFailureHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="concurrentSessionControlStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
        ref="sessionRegistry" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/LoginSuccess" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="loginFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/LoginFailed" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Register a custom logout filter -->
<beans:bean id="customLogoutFilter" class="xxx.security.LogoutFilterWrapper">
    <beans:property name="logoutSuccessfulUrl" value="/public/auth/login.htmlx" />
    <beans:property name="logoutSuccessfulUrlAdmin" value="/public/auth/admlogin.htmlx" />
    <beans:property name="logoutSuccessfulUrlInactivity"
        value="/public/auth/timedout.htmlx" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Register a concurrent session filter. This will limit the number of 
    sessions a user can have -->
<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl"
        value="/public/error/multi-login-not-supported.htmlx" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Register a filter to log in as a different user -->    
<beans:bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customDetailService" />
    <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_switch_user" />
    <beans:property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />
    <beans:property name="targetUrl" value="/" />
</beans:bean>


<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customAuthenticationFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="customLogoutFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />

            <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

    <!-- Configure the filter security interceptor. URL patterns default to 
        Apache Ant path syntax -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/xyz_product*" access="ROLE_XYZ_PRODUCT" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/root/user/index.htmlx" access="ROLE_XYZ_PRODUCT" />

    <!-- Allow unrestrictricted access to assets -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" filters="none" />

    <!-- Allow unrestrictricted access to public areas -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" filters="none" />

    <!-- Allow unrestrictricted access to generated resources -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/faces/**" filters="none" />

    <!-- Enforce role-based access for login success servlet -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/LoginSuccess"
        access="ROLE_RESTRICTED,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN_APP,ROLE_PHYSICIAN,ROLE_NURSE" />

    <!-- Enforce role-based access for user area -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/root/user/**" access="ROLE_PHYSICIAN,ROLE_NURSE" />

    <!-- Enforce role-based access for admin area -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/root/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN_APP" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/root/admin/user/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN_APP" />


    // ommitted ...

     </http>

    </beans:beans>
```

Here's my facelets page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="j_username" value="" styleClass="textInput" size="50"/>    
    <p>Click <h:commandLink value="here" action="/j_spring_security_switch_user"/> to switch to 
        user </p>
</h:form>
```

Error in the logs:

> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
>   - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object

Comment: What does the debug log say about how the request is processed? You should be able to see which filters it passes through and in particular whether the `SwitchUserFilter` is invoked.

Comment: I updated the question with the log of filers fired. `SwitchUserFilter` is NOT fired.

Comment: If the filter isn't invoked, then it's not in the filter chain. I don't see your logout filter either. Please post your configuration.

Comment: Sorry about the delay; I updated the description with the complete spring-security config. This is a prod app written four yrs ago in 2.5 and later migrated to spring security 3.0.2.

Comment: You haven't described what goes wrong or given any relevant log output. "RunAsManager did not change Authentication object" is not an error, just a debug message (one of many). Also you should be using an up to date version of 3.0.x. If you are still using 3.0.2 then your app is probably susceptible to published vulnerabilitiies.

Comment: Debugging updates: SwitchUserFilter#requiresSwitchUser always returns the url as the root url and not "/j_spring_security_switch_user".

Comment: Also, I can't upgrade from 3.0.3 since this fix: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1584 breaks 3.0.4, raising a critical bug in 7 production apps. I get a 404 on login since the url is being stripped out of orchestra's conversation context ids which are required by the controllers.

Comment: Given the facelets page, what would prevent the page from submitting the action url:/j_spring_security_switch_user to switchUserFilter's Request? Am i missing something?

Comment: Would appreciate your inputs -- thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. The problem was with my jsf page not sending j_username to SwitchUserFilter when I bind the jsf action to '/j_spring_security_switch_user'. However, a passthrough through a controller binding works.

I blogged my experience here:

http://www.reverttoconsole.com/blog/spring/switch-user-su-like-behavior-in-spring/